# Desura fails to run: Error loading library libcef_desura.so

Tags: 11.10, games

I've been using desura for a few weeks now on 11.04 without any problems, however when I upgraded to 11.10 today and reinstalled desura I get this error message:

```
include/SharedObjectLoader.h:75 - Error loading library libcef_desura.so:
'libplc4.so.0d:   wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32'
```

I'm running 64-bit 11.10 Ubuntu desktop. I had a few errors before this one but I managed to fix them. Desura actually runs however I cannot see or click on anything on the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im the developer of Desura and the one responsible for breaking it last night. :(

There was an update that tried to use your system libraries over the ones bundled with Desura but there was a bug in the script that caused 32 bit libs to be used instead of the 64 bit ones (when your running 64bit Desura).

Force update desura (ether via the menu or running Desura with -f "./desura -f") and it should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I updated but the error message still appears.

Comment: Nevermind, I copletely uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Seems to work fine now.